# Select distinct values from each column in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, distinct

Im trying to select distinct values from each column inside a given table. My Query is lacking performance due to the creation of many MapReduce Jobs and im looking for a better solution.

My Table contains the following values:

```
last_30: a  
last_90: a, b, a    
last_180: b, c
```

The desired output would be the following:

```
last_30#a  
last_90#a  
last_90#b   
last_180#b  
last_180#c
```

Using the following Query i get the desired output, it is not very performant though because it loops through the table several times:

```
SELECT distinct concat('last_30', exploded_last_30.key) 
FROM table
LATERAL VIEW explode(last_30) exploded_last_30 AS key
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct concat('last_90', exploded_last_90.key) 
FROM table
LATERAL VIEW explode(last_90) exploded_last_90 AS key
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct concat('last_180', exploded_last_180.key) 
FROM table
LATERAL VIEW explode(last_180) exploded_last_180 AS key
```

Can you think of a faster way to create the desired output?

Greets

:::Update:::

Using your solution i came up with the following Query:

```
    select distinct *
    from (
        select explode( map_keys( map(
                                      concat('firstname#',a.exploded_firstname), '1', 
                                      concat('lastname#', a.exploded_lastname), '1', 
                                      concat('gender#', a.exploded_gender), '1',
                                      concat('last_30#', a.exploded_last_30), '1',
                                      concat('last_90#', a.exploded_last_90), '1'   
                                     ) 
                                )  
                      )
        from (
              select
                exploded_firstname.key as exploded_firstname, 
                exploded_lastname.key as exploded_lastname, 
                exploded_gender.key as exploded_gender,
                exploded_last_30.key as exploded_last_30,
                exploded_last_90.key as exploded_last_90
              from table
              LATERAL VIEW explode(firstname) exploded_firstname AS key, value
              LATERAL VIEW explode(lastname) exploded_lastname AS key, value
              LATERAL VIEW explode(gender) exploded_gender AS key, value
              LATERAL VIEW explode(last_30) exploded_last_30 AS key
              LATERAL VIEW explode(last_90) exploded_last_90 AS key
          ) as a 
      ) as b;
```

Still facing two problems though:

- I did not describe the problem to its full extent, the sample data I
  provided only includes primitive datatypes. In the real table Maps and Arrays     are present as well. Hitting an Array or Map only
  containing the 'NULL' Value will return no Output at all
- Secondly, adding more fields
  to this query prevents the compiler from creating MapReduce Jobs to
  execute the request. Here are the MapReduce Times for 14 and 15 fields
  respectively:

  ```
  Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 26 seconds 60 msec
  OK
  Time taken: 142.896 seconds

  Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 29 seconds 310 msec
  OK
  Time taken: 257.807 seconds
  ```

As you can see the Total MapReduce Time is approximately linear while the Total Time Taken increases greatly. You guys got any advide on those two issues?

Answer (score 0):

Union will force multiple reads of the table. To avoid it you could use maps to de-duplicate data of the single row and then explode it (This will pivot your data). For de-duplication use column values as map keys and a constant for the value of the map.

If there are no duplicate values between the rows, then this will be a single scan operation:

```
  select explode( map_keys( map(concat(customer_id, '#', customer_fname), '1'
             , concat(customer_id, '#', customer_lname), '1'
             , concat(customer_id, '#', customer_email), '1'
             , concat(customer_id, '#', customer_street), '1'
             , concat(customer_id, '#', customer_city), '1'
             , concat(customer_id, '#', customer_state), '1'
             , concat(customer_id, '#', customer_zipcode), '1'
      ) ) ) from customers
```

If there are duplicates produced by different rows, then add distinct, but this will force a reduce stage and will be slower.

Also maps, can be used to pivot data :D